# How do i combine 3 queries into 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

Battles

```
--battleId(primary)--gameId(foreign)--endTime
```

BattleParticipants

```
--battleParticipantId(primary)--userId(foreign)--someNumerical--score--battleId(foreign)
```

Given userId, i want to get only *ended battle* data for each battle user participated in **with additional player rank information and total number of player participated in battle information**.*Ended battle* means battles only with endTime smaller than current_time

returned battle data should include:

```
battleId:
endTime:
gameId:
score:
someNumerical:
rankOfPlayerInBattle:
totalNumberOfPlayersParticipatedInBattle:
```

for each battle player participated.

With below query i can get `battleId,endTime,gameId,score,someNumerical` as i want:

```
SELECT b.battleId,b.endTime,b.gameId,bp.score,bp.someNumerical FROM battles b  JOIN battleparticipants bp ON b.battleId=bp.battleId WHERE bp.userId="someuserid" AND b.endTime<CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Given battleId and userId this query returns me **rank of user** in that battle:

```
SET @i=0;
             SELECT battleId, userId,score, @i:=@i+1 AS myRank 
              FROM battleparticipants  WHERE battleId="asd1234" AND userId="someuserid"
              ORDER BY score DESC
```

Given battleId this query gives me total number of players participated in that battle:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM battleparticipants WHERE battleId="asd1234"
```

So given those seperated queries how do i retrieve data i want in one query ? (i dont really need to use above queries i just gave them as example since they get datas i want seperately)

i cant add fiddle because for some reason create code is throwing error. for now i add pictures of tables and data:

Battles table:
[image]

BattleParticipants table:
[image]

Below query wrong result:
[image]

Comment: use your first query with the `JOIN`, append `GROUP BY b.battleId`. Include 'COUNT(*)` in the result. Then introduce the ranking. BTW what mysql version?

Comment: 8.0.19 is my msql version

Comment: question is still active

Comment: Can you include some sample data in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) and share its link. For accuracy can you include the expected results of the desired query for your sample daata in the question too.

Comment: i edited my question. couldnt add fiddle because it gave me lots of error while trying to create table but i hope my edit will be helpful

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` and then copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.battleId,b.endTime,b.gameId,bp.score,bp.someNumerical , RANK()OVER(PARITITON BY b.battleId, bp.userId order by score desc) rankOfPlayerInBattle , BP_C.CNT totalNumberOfPlayersParticipatedInBattle
FROM battles b  
JOIN battleparticipants bp ON b.battleId=bp.battleId 
JOIN (SELECT battleId , COUNT(*) CNT FROM battleparticipants GROUP BY battleId)  BP_C ON BP_C.battleId=bp.battleId 
WHERE bp.userId="someuserid" AND b.endTime<CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

You can use above SQL.

Comment: Please share input data and expected output.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: `GROUP BY battleId` in the subquery as a guess